# Cosmos DB query to join child documents on main document

Tags: nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a bunch of documents in my Cosmos DB that has the following format:

```
{
    "name": "Name 1",
    "allowedusrs": [
        {
            "id": "UserId 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "UserId 2"
        }
    ],
    "parent": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Name 2",
            "id": "058392a4-f72b-4f7c-aa10-459b182e102b"
        },
        {
            "name": "Name 3",
            "id": "afa3351d-dbed-49a0-8501-b61c1983d7c9"
        }
    ],
    "id": "07ac90c3-4af9-47ab-be15-116df328e88f",
}
```

child documents:

```
{
    "name": "Name 2",
    "allowedusrs": [
        {
            "id": "UserId 3"
        }
    ],
    "parent": "07ac90c3-4af9-47ab-be15-116df328e88f",
    "children": [
        {
            ...
        }
    ],
    "id": "058392a4-f72b-4f7c-aa10-459b182e102b",
}
```

A few notes about the above data:

- I want to query the hierarchy based on the user Id
- A user may be a member of multiple trees (The above documents is for one specific tree)
- Only one userId may exist per tree
- I want to start building the tree from where the userId is allowed

Effectively the outcome that I would like is the following:

```
[{
    "name": "Name 1",
    "allowedusrs": [
        {
            "id": "UserId 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "UserId 2"
        }
    ],
    "parent": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Name 2",
            "allowedusrs": [
                {
                    "id": "UserId 3"
                }
            ],
            "parent": "07ac90c3-4af9-47ab-be15-116df328e88f",
            "children": [
                {
                    ...
                }
            ],
            "id": "058392a4-f72b-4f7c-aa10-459b182e102b",
        }
  
    ],
    "id": "07ac90c3-4af9-47ab-be15-116df328e88f",
},
{
    ...Tree 2 which the user has access too
}]
```

So far, I have achieved to be able to query the top-level document of the tree where the userId is present.

This I have achieved with the following query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.parent, c.allowedusrs, c.children FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.allowedusrs, {'id': @userid}, true )
```

However, as you can probably imagine, this is not enough - I want to be able to query for the child documents and embed them into their top level document. So a recursive function.

I'm unsure where to start as this is slightly different to regular SQL - So I would very much appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.